# Can't use System.Drawing in C# console application

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

I'm trying to make a program that would create images in C#. It would make some calculations, without any user interface, then export a bitmap image.
For that last part I tried to use System.Drawing as it seemed to be the easiest. But I just can't.

I'm using Visual Studio, I created a C# console project, and the framework is .NET (5, 6, 7, when I change it the problem stays the same).
Under the project name, there is no "reference" tree, only "dependencies" where I can add either a COM reference, a project reference or a shared project reference (note that I'm translating the interface... there can be some mistakes). There is no "assembly" section in the reference manager.

I can add a COM reference to System.Drawing (either v2.0 or v2.4), but I get a warning MSB3290 "Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type library... Type library 'System_Drawing' was exported from a CLR assembly and cannot be re-imported as a CLR assembly.".

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong, and what could be the solutions or alternatives...

I tried to change the framework version, but honestly I'm already out of imagination.
I looked for that problem on the internet, the answer were:

- don't use .NET core (I am not)
- re-install NuGet packages (I'm not using any)
- add a reference to System.Form (same problem with that reference)

Comment: Open the nuget manager on the project and add "System.Drawing.Common" and maybe "System.Drawing.Primitives".

Comment: [Skia](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp) is not an option?

Comment: OK my bad, I guess.I had created a Console Application, which was using the framework ".NET" in whatever version. The project properties was showing "Framework: .NET 6.0", and I could choose other version and .NET core as well.

I needed to create a "Console Application (.NET Framework)", which uses the framework ".NET Framework". That's quite confusing. I am confused.

Comment: FYI .net 5+ is the successor to .net core (they basically just dropped the "core" part)

Comment: Ooooooh ok thanks for the precision, that's a lot clearer